# run fedora and windows OS at a time

Tags: windows, linux

My main OS is windows xp and I create a partition where I have installed fedora. I have 1gb of ram and 500gb of HDD. Shall I run both the OS at a time? If so how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate question for this site. In any case, would running one partition within a VM on the other OS be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running a virtual machine.  I generally run it the other way around with Windoze in a virtual machine, and I generally give Windoze 1gb of memory to play with on its' own.  I'm not saying that it will not work, but you may want to look at putting some more memory in that box.

Take a look at [VMWare Server](http://www.vmware.com/support/product-support/server.html), but I think I saw that product hit EOL, and you can look at [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) as well.  I have used both over the years, but I am partial to VirtaulBox.

Comment: can you tell me the steps what to do?

Comment: I would download VirtualBox and go through the wizard to create a virtual new machine.  It will ask you questions about what OS you are installing, CPU allotment, memory and disk allocations for the VM.  I'm not really sure on the specs of you machine so I can't make any recommendations, but if Fedora is not in the list it should be fine with RedHat.  Vast amounts of information can be found on the subject by asking our good friend Google about VirtualBox and Fedora  (include version numbers for each)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run two OSes at once, you can, however dualboot (install windows, then linux, and switch between boots), or run a VM (install one OS, install a VM software - virtualbox supports [windows and most recent redhat varients](https://www.virtualbox.org/), install the second os inside a VM instance - which is to say start the VM software, run through the wizard, and installing it there.).

I'd generally have the OS you use more, and has more requirements for graphics as the host OS when virtualizing. You could also run *both* oses you work with as VMs to take advantage of snapshots and to allow for easier backups, if you don't have heavy performance needs..

If dualbooting installing windows, then linux is easier, and you can then select which OS to boot at the bootloader.